# JSPX customising xml tags

Tags: java, xml, jsp, jspx

In some tutorials about `.jspx` pages i saw constructions like:

```
<body>
   <books>
      <book>NewBook</book>
    </books>
</body>
```

... but i didn't understand how to let the `jspx` know what does `<books>` means.

So, how to declare this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure if it's the same, but look at [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_custom_tags.htm) link!